# POV-Ray: what does a function in a pigment statement do?

Tags: povray

This `pigment` statement appears in a code I found on the web, where `depth` is a number:

```
pigment{
    function{(depth+1)/3} 
    color_map{[0 rgb <0,0,0>][1/3 rgb <0,0,1>][2/3 rgb <1,0,1>][1 rgb <1,1,1>]}
}
```

What does `function{(depth+1)/3}` do? As I understand, this is the constant function returning `(depth+1)/3`. What is the role of this function in the `pigment` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I understand now. That's easy.

If depth = 1, (depth+1)/3 = 2/3, so the color map returns the color corresponding to 2/3, that is, `rgb<1,0,1>`.

If depth = 2, (depth+1)/3 = 1, so the color map returns `rgb<1,1,1>`.

If depth = 0.5, (depth+1)/3 = 0.5, so the color map returns the color interpolated between `rgb<0,0,1>` (1/3) and `rgb<1,0,1>` (2/3).

A `color_map` is a map, and the value of the function gives the "key" of this map.